# ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR with caddy

Tags: docker, caddy

I deployed my .NET 8 API under Docker on my VPS (Debian 12)
My docker image exposes on port 5000.
I installed Caddy and made this setting (Caddyfile).

```
{
     email myemail@gmail.com
}

mydns.com {

root * /usr.share/caddy

file_server

reverse_proxy localhost:5000

log {
     output file /var/log/caddy/logs.log
    }
}
```

When I go to the URL corresponding to my DNS I get this error message:

ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

It seemed to me that Caddy would install an automatic certificate (via Let'sEncrypt)

Do you have any idea what I might have done wrong please?

Comment: That's a very generic error message -- it can be produced for several different errors. Which _specific_ `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` did you get?

Comment: (Think about using `openssl s_client -connect` as one way to get a more in-depth error message if you aren't getting anything from your current client; and, of course, make sure you're reading caddy's logs and including a description of what you find there in the question).

Comment: Among other things, when you're configuring for `mydns.com`, Caddy will only request a certificate for _exactly_ `mydns.com` -- not `www.mydns.com` -- so be sure your configuration precisely matches the actual name used.

Comment: The problem was the dns. I noted mydns.com instead of www.mydsn.com. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Glad to help! BTW, for the future, questions about _using and configuring_ tools (including Caddy) as opposed to _writing_ tools is generally better suited to [unix.se]; Stack Overflow keeps a very tight focus on questions about writing code.